# Does anxiety about weight or eating cause people to become overweight?

Tags: human-biology, psychology, diet

A while ago I saw [this TED talk about the futility of dieting](http://blog.ted.com/why-your-brain-doesnt-want-you-to-lose-weight-sandra-aamodt-at-tedglobal-2013/). The speaker suggests that a body maintains a homeostatic weight point and returns to that weight after dieting has stopped:

> Turns out the brain is an incredibly efficient regulator of body
>   weight. Isn’t weight loss about how much you eat versus how much
>   energy you burn? Nope, it’s not that simple an equation: it turns out
>   that hunger and energy use are controlled by the brain, mostly behind
>   the scenes, and this unconscious force is stronger than mere
>   willpower. **The brain has its own sense of what your body should weigh
>   — no matter what you believe — called the set point, which has a range
>   of about 15 pounds.** While lifestyle changes can shift your weight
>   within this range, it’s much harder to move outside of it.

The speaker suggests that once she gave up dieting, she actually lost weight. Since then I've seen a number of other anecdotal reports of people losing weight once they let go of the need to diet and started to "eat anything they wanted".

This makes me ask - **does anxiety about weight and attempts to control one's eating cause people to put on weight?** In other words, if there's some unresolved anxiety issue in one's life, does it cause the human body to start preparing for hard times by storing extra fat?

Comment: yes, anxiety can changes hormonal state of our body,which may reduce catabolic enzyme that leads to grow more fat. So, anxiety may be a cause of over weight